# How can I add "http" to the "src" attributes?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape content from some websites, this is the websites HTML:

```
<div class="answer-given-body ugc-base">
  <p><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F61d%2F61d6042d-e4dd-41d9-9a5c-0ceb481ddbc9%2FphpKFGb9B.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fd72%2Fd72dfa6c-8e50-475a-86cf-678a04ae4606%2FphpQZYPYo.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4c7%2F4c775a01-8590-4b93-bc20-03d282586f95%2FphpE7XFWI.png"/></p>
  </div>`
```

In the above HTML inside the `img` tag in the `src` attribute, it does not start with "HTTP" so the images are not showing when I save the HTML file, how can I edit the `src` attributes and add "HTTP" before them?

Comment: when you navigate to a webpage (as a human) are you seeing the image? if so then this is referenced URL, and this is a common practice you will see on most websites.

Comment: To replace all the src that doesn't contain `http`. You can simple use python builtin string method `replace`.  `my_html.replace('src="/', 'src="http:/')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add "https" to the tags `src`, you can access the `src` attribute using `[]` and and "https" as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
<div class="answer-given-body ugc-base">
  <p><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F61d%2F61d6042d-e4dd-41d9-9a5c-0ceb481ddbc9%2FphpKFGb9B.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fd72%2Fd72dfa6c-8e50-475a-86cf-678a04ae4606%2FphpQZYPYo.png"/><img alt="" src="//d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4c7%2F4c775a01-8590-4b93-bc20-03d282586f95%2FphpE7XFWI.png"/></p>
  </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Select all the `img` tags
for tag in soup.select(".answer-given-body.ugc-base img"):
    tag["src"] = "https:" + tag["src"]

print(soup.prettify())
```

Output:

```
<div class="answer-given-body ugc-base">
 <p>
  <img alt="" src="https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F61d%2F61d6042d-e4dd-41d9-9a5c-0ceb481ddbc9%2FphpKFGb9B.png"/>
  <img alt="" src="https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2Fd72%2Fd72dfa6c-8e50-475a-86cf-678a04ae4606%2FphpQZYPYo.png"/>
  <img alt="" src="https://d2vlcm61l7u1fs.cloudfront.net/media%2F4c7%2F4c775a01-8590-4b93-bc20-03d282586f95%2FphpE7XFWI.png"/>
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: but some links have HTTP in src but this code adding HTTP for all the links whether the src link have HTTP or not please help me how to add if condition there